# Addition of Perpendicular Vectors in two ways

Tags: vectors

I have a Force Vector $= 100N$, making an Angle $= 45$ degrees. 
When I find their Components trigonometrically, I get $70N$ each; as

$$F_x = 100\cos(45) = 70N$$
$$F_y = 100\sin(45) = 70N$$

Verifying the result, by Head-to-Tail method, I get $70N + 70N = 140N$.

Why is there descripancy or where am I making a mistake?
Please help.

Comment: Which angle do you mean, this means angle to...

Comment: Do you mean the angle to the $x$ axis?

Comment: Yes, Angle = 45 degrees with x-axis, making a Right-angle triangle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. See this [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to write math here in a more readable way.

Comment: The sum of two vectors is not the sum of the absolute values of these vectors.

Answer (score 1):

When you add vectors using the head-to-tail method, you still have to maintain the correct directions of the vectors. When you add the two component vectors that you’ve computed using this method, you get something like this:

[image]

Since the two dotted vectors are perpendicular, the length of the resulting vector is given by the Pythagorean theorem: $\sqrt{70^2+70^2}\approx 99$. This isn’t exactly $100$ because you truncated the actual value of the length of the components ($50\sqrt2 = 70.71\dots$) to $70$. If you use the better approximation of $70.7$, the resulting length is much close to the original $100$.

What you effectively did was to add two vectors that point in the same direction, which is not what you’ve got after decomposing the original force vector.

Comment: Thank you very much, amd, for such an elaborate reply. I fully agree with it.
I just wonder, why so many school books keep publicizing that; with the Head-to-Tail method, we can just add 2 or more vectors to find the Resultant vector.
Regards.

Comment: @RoshanAkhterAbbasi I get the impression that either the way you were taught the Head-to-Tail method or the way that you’ve interpreted what you were taught is incorrect. You do line the vectors up head to tail, but as I wrote, you have to maintain their directions when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Pretending that $\frac 12\sqrt 2=0.7$, which is not correct, your force vector is $F=(70,70)$.  You have resolved it correctly into $F_x=(70,0)$ and $F_y=(0,70)$.  When you add these together you add the components and get back to $(70,70)$ as you should.  The fact that the sum of the magnitudes is $140$ is not important.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I am interested in finding the cause, academically. Physics teaches us the 3 methods to solve the Vectors:
(a)- Trigonometrically
(b)- Using Pythagoras Theorem
(c)- Head-to-Tail method of Adding Vectors

My confusion is why do I get different answers by using the 2 ways.

Regards.

Comment: Adding head to tail does not mean you add the magnitudes.  You add the components, as I did above.  You can only add the magnitudes when they are in the same direction.

Comment: Thanks again. Let me figure out your perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You have a component of force in the x direction and a component in the y direction  when you add them together the components each maintain their direction.

you could write this as $70\mathbf i + 70 \mathbf j$ or $(70,0) + (0,70) = (70,70)$ depending on which notation you choose to use.

You can't just add the magnitudes of vectors in different directions and get the magnitude of the sum.

In fact we have the "triangle inequality" which says. $\|F_x + F_y\|\le \|F_x\|+\|F_y\|$

The magnitude of the vector is $\|F_x + F_y \| = \sqrt {F_x^2 + F_y^2}$

Comment: Thanks, Doug M, for your time. Let me try to understand; what you said; or let me-re-phrase my question before making another interrupt.